# Testing / Packaging a python application from a Paster template

Tags: python, testing, packaging, software-packaging

Using the [Modern-Package](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/modern-package-template) template, I can see how to build 'libraries' or modules that other applications import, but what isn't clear is how to build scripts for console use?

If I follow the instructions as I understand them, I do my development in the `<pkgname>/src/<pkgname>/` directory, pop down the tree, `python setup.py build`.

However, this simply creates the same style of source tree, like `build/lib<whatever>/<pkgname>/__init__py`.

Im quite possibly not understanding this correctly at all but what is the 'proper' way to test and package applications that you should end up being able to execute directly?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering; my solution was to use `python setup.py develop --user` and add `~/.local/bin` to your path. Bingo.